# Using IQueryable in join causes StackOverflow Exception

Tags: linq-to-sql

Does anyone know why this causes a stackoverflow exception:

```
public IQueryable<Category> LoadCategories(bool onlyCatsWithProducts, ...)
{
    var db = new DbDataContext();
    var res = db.Categories.AsQueryable();

    if (onlyCatsWithProducts)
        res = from p in db.Products
              from c in res
              where p.CategoryID == c.ID
              select c;
    ...
    return res;
}
```

**Update**

Changed the example code to make clear why I'm assigning to a variable then reassign it later. Basically it's because I'm writing a function to return categories from the database and I take in several parameters (e.g. onlyCatsWithProducts) where each filter the result set only if they have a value. Note this is still not my actual code because my queries are more complicated and I'm just wanting to show the simplest query needed to reproduce the error.

Comment: Is this the actual code? If so, I'm guessing there's a typo...what is v?

Comment: Thanks fixed typo. I just simplified my code a lot for the example so not my actual code.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `.AsQueryable()`. You might want to try explicitly setting the output type to the underlying interface rather than using `var` or `AsQueryable()`. I'm not sure if that would solve your StackOverflow issue when assigning the expression tree recursively here.

Comment: @JimWooley The purpose of `.AsQueryable()` is because `db.Categories` is of type `System.Data.Linq.Table<T>` and later I assign a query of type `System.Data.Linq.DataQuery<T>` to that variable. I could of course just declare the variable as `IQueryable<Category> res = db.Categories;` but that does not help fix the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Michael, in answering his own question, said he had no idea why swapping the order of his `from`'s fixed his problem.

Like this caused the stack overflow:

```
var res = db.Categories.AsQueryable();
res = from p in db.Products
      from c in res
      where p.CategoryID == c.ID
      select c;
```

Like this didn't:

```
var res = db.Categories.AsQueryable();
res = from c in res
      from p in db.Products
      where p.CategoryID == c.ID
      select c;
```

Here's why. These two above queries get translated, by the compiler, to this code:

```
var res = db.Categories.AsQueryable();
var q = db.Products
    .SelectMany(p => res, (p, c) => new { p, c })
    .Where(x => x.p.CategoryID == x.c.ID)
    .Select(x => x.c);
```

and this respectively:

```
var res = db.Categories.AsQueryable();
var q = res
    .SelectMany(c => db.Products, (c, p) => new { c, p })
    .Where(x => x.p.CategoryID == x.c.ID)
    .Select(x => x.c);
```

The first one contains the lambda `p => res` which is essentially capturing a reference to the `res` variable. Since `res` gets reassigned every time the query is run in references the reassigned version of itself and bang - stack overflow!

In the second one the `res` is outside of any lamdbas, so the reference isn't captured and only the original reference is used - i.e. `res = db.Categories.AsQueryable()` and this doesn't change when the query is executed.

It would probably be just as easy to use:

```
var res = from c in db.Categories
          from p in db.Products
          where p.CategoryID == c.ID
          select c;
```

I hope this helps clear up what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Why create a variable and then re-assign the variable straight after, using the variable in the assignment? Your query is probably doing some sort of infinite recursion, causing a `StackOverFlowException`. Try something like:

```
var res = 
  from c in DB.Instance.Categories
  from p in DB.Instance.Products
  where p.CategoryID == c.ID
  select c;
```

Update:

Try something like the below. I think you need to avoid using `res` in the assignment of `res`.

```
IQueryable<Category> res;

if (onlyCatsWithProducts)
    res = from p in db.Products
          from c in db.Categories.AsQueryable()
          where p.CategoryID == c.ID
          select c;
```

Comment: Changed question to reflect the purpose of the variable. Your code does work but my function takes in a number of parameters (not just one as is the case in my clarified example) that alter the query depending on what's passed in and as a result doing it all in one query is going to make it a lot more complicated. I could do it if it's the first filter applied but three of my filters have complicated joins that require that syntax and so that's a number of if else statements for all the permutations which is not that nice.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, after posting I discovered swapping the order seems to fix the problem. Got no idea why though:

```
var db = new DbDataContext();
var res = db.Categories.AsQueryable();
res = from c in res
      from p in db.Products
      where p.CategoryID == c.ID
      select c;
```